# Bootstrap の mixin 利用時のライセンスは？

Tags: css, ライセンス, twitter-bootstrap, mit-license

[Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) は LESS を使えば、mixin で部分的に利用できます。

では Bootstrap を部分的に利用した LESS を CSS にコンパイルして配布することは、ライセンス上、問題ないのでしょうか。

また、配布できる場合、ライセンス表記はどのようにすれば良いでしょうか。Bootstrap のライセンス (MIT) のほか、自身の選択したライセンス (たとえば Apache2) を併記して良いのでしょうか。ライセンスの適用範囲が不明瞭になるように思うのですが、問題ないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

はい、Bootstrapを利用したLESSをCSSにコンパイルして配布することは、ライセンス上問題ありません。このライブラリはMITライセンスを採用しており、加工と再配布、派生作品に別のライセンスを採用することなどを許しています。

再配布する方法はいくつかあります。例えば、再配布するあなたの作品に以下のファイルを同梱する方法はいかがでしょうか。

- ライセンス表記を含めたBootstrapのソースコード
- あなたの作品のライセンスを表記したLICENSEファイル

別の方法が良いですか？別の方法の例を挙げると、Rubyはライセンス表記が必要なソースコードを使用しており、その表記を以下のように別ファイル(LEGAL)として記述しています。

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/LEGAL

Comment: ありがとうございます。回答・自身の調査でいくつかははっきりしました。

- **加工と再配布を許す** → Bootstrap + 自身の LESS でできたコンパイルを配布は問題なし
- **派生物に別のライセンスを採用できる** → 私のライセンス付与は問題なし
- MIT ライセンスに従うために **Bootstrap のライセンス表記が必要**

元の LESS ファイルについては上記で十分だと思います。2つを組み合わせて出来上がった CSS についてはどういう扱いになるのでしょうか。

Comment: 2つを組み合わせて出来上がったCSSファイルは、派生物と言えます。とすると、CSSファイルにもBootstrapのライセンスの表記は必要だと思います。